# How do you use the preprocessor for making a cross-platform library?

Tags: c++, graphics, cross-platform, c-preprocessor, platform

I want to use the same `#ifdef` approach used by WxWidgets , SDL etc. The only problem is I don't know how to use it.

Say I want to make a class that draws a rectangle. I want it to use cairo when on X11 platforms (i.e linux) and GDI on win32 platforms :

```
class graphics
{
void drawRect(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
/*if on win32*/
HDC myHdc = ::BeginPaint(myHwnd,&mypstr);
::Rectangle(myHdc,x,y,w,h); 
::EndPaint(myHwnd,&mypstr);

/*if on x11*/
cairo_surface_t* s = cairo_xlib_surface_create(/* args */); 
cairo_t* c = cairo_create(s);
cairo_rectangle(c,x,y,w,h);
// etc. etc.
}
};
```

How would I use `#ifdef` or something else to do this?

Comment: Don't WxWidgets and SDL provide the preprocessor examples you're looking for?

Comment: (+1) The concept represented by the question title, worths an upvote. Don't have an answer, reading others developers answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can, prefer to put platform specific methods into separate translation units.  This will allow cleaner & more readable code and easier to develop and maintain.  IMHO, the build process should determine which platform specific modules to incorporate.

For example:
**rectangle.hpp:**

```
struct Rectangle
{
  void draw(int upper_left_corner_x, int upper_left_corner_y,
            unsigned int length, unsigned int width);
}
```

Now the platform specific files:
**rectangle_wx_widgets.cpp:**

```
#include "rectangle.hpp"
void
Rectangle ::
draw(int upper_left_corner_x, int upper_left_corner_y,
            unsigned int length, unsigned int width)
{
// wxWidgets specific code here.
}
```

**rectangle_qt.cpp:**

```
#include "rectangle.hpp"
void
Rectangle ::
draw(int upper_left_corner_x, int upper_left_corner_y,
            unsigned int length, unsigned int width)
{
// QT specific code here.
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "rectangl.hpp"
int main(void)
{
  Rectangle r;
  r.draw(50, 50, 10, 5);
  return 0;
}
```

The above code has no conditional preprocessor directives.  The `main` function draws a rectangle regardless of the platform.  The specifics of the platform have been removed from `main` because they are not important.  So, without changing any compiler switches or worrying about which preprocessor identifier is defined, one can see that `main` unconditionally draws a rectangle.

To draw using a wxWidgets platform, the build process would use `rectangle_wx_widgets.cpp`.  To draw using QT, the `rectangle_qt.cpp` file would be used, but not both.  As this illustration shows, no code is changed in order to produce code for either platform.  One could tailor the build process so the command `build wxWidgets` would include the proper translation units.  Thus passing a parameter to the build process generates the platform specific executable.

Comment: I agree that your solution seems cleaner. (+1), but I sense one or two problems, what if I want to change something in the header? e.g 
if windows `typedef HDC painter` else `typedef cairo_t painter`

Comment: @IntermediateHacker:  The platform specific files can include platform specific headers.  In your reply example, you would create a generic `paint` method that is framework specific.  There would be a `paint` for Windows API and a `paint` for Cairo.  And propagate this down as far as possible.  The objective is to reduce the quantity of conditional preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 2):

cross-platform doesn't mean only unix vs windows. also, the predefined cpp directives may be compiler dependent. 
boost platform selection source code is a good start to see how this can be done the right way. see [config/select_platform_config.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/config/select_platform_config.hpp)
you may also want to take a look at [cmake](http://www.cmake.org) which sets some [platform dependent defines](http://www.openguru.com/2009/04/cmake-detecting-platformoperating.html)

Comment: sorry for the "unix vs windows" implication, it was not intended. I just wanted to explain the point.

Answer (score 0):

They are quite direct.

You want something like this:

```
#ifndef WIN32
// something for X11
#else
// something for Windows
#endif
```

It's just a matter of knowing the default conditionals  (like WIN32 in this case). There are conditionals for operating system, compilers and a lot of portability stuff.

For this case, look at the windows.h header file. It might contain more info for you.

Comment: you probably want `ifdef` so that you can support more than two.

Answer (score 0):

There are predefined platform variables like WIN32 that you can use:

```
#ifdef WIN32
....
#else
....
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

For a list of platform-specific macros, see also http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/fixes.html#fixes.build.cpp

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick to it that I don't see others mentioning (edit: sysfault mentioned it).  There's two different concepts at work here.  The preprocessor commands will differ depending on both your target, and your compiler.  Namely,  to tell which compiler you're using ([GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) vs [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    /*MSVC*/
#endif
#ifdef __GNUC__
    /*GCC*/
#endif
```

MSVC will only compile for Windows targets (as far as we're concerned today), and GCC targets everything.  For GCC, to tell *which* OS it's targeting:

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__ 
    /* Windows */
#endif
#ifdef BSD
    /* BSD */
#endif
#ifdef __linux__
    /* linux */
#endif
#ifdef __APPLE__
    /* OSX */
#endif
```

Also, sometimes you need to know something specific to the processor, but not the operating system:

```
__CHAR_UNSIGNED__
    GCC defines this macro if and only if the data type char is unsigned on the target machine.
__BYTE_ORDER__
__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
__ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
__ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__
    __BYTE_ORDER__ is defined to one of the values __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__, __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__, or __ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__ to reflect the layout of multi-byte and multi-word quantities in memory.
__LP64__
_LP64
    These macros are defined, with value 1, if (and only if) the compilation is for a target where long int and pointer both use 64-bits and int uses 32-bit.
```

And many many others